# Move the last 4 non-blank cells from a number of rows

Tags: excel

I have done a bit of digging but had no luck, I'm looking to move the last 4 non-blank cells from a range of into a specific row to align them.

```
2A   29H    0   0   0   0                       
24H  88H    13  7   4   0                       
35H  44H     71H    7   3   7   1                   
3A   62H     72A    8   3   8   4                   
17A 13  3   16  6                           
61A  67H     75A    10  2   8   3                   
25H  49H    16  3   5   1                       
36H  39A     51H     56H     78A     82H    16  6   8   3       
20H  29H     45H     48H     79H     82H     90H    22  10  3   1   
20A  28A     44H     46A     62H     69H     75H     84H    16  7   7   3
```

Here is my list starting from Column E1 in the top left corner, could anyone think of a formula which will do this?

So basically I need to move the numeric characters away from the values with a number and character.

Comment: Easy with a macro.....is a macro approach acceptable??

Comment: I've had a go but i'm not too good with them

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't mind it being in a separate sheet, try

```
=IF(COLUMN()<COLUMN($AA$1),
  IF(ISTEXT(Sheet1!A1),Sheet1!A1,""),
  INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$Z1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$A1:$Z1),0),0)+COLUMN()-COLUMN($AA$1)))
```

in A1 of sheet 2, and pull across.

This will display the cells containing text starting at sheet2!A1, and the ones containing numbers starting at sheet2!AA1.

[image]

Or to prevent zeroes appearing after the last number:-

```
=IF(COLUMN()<COLUMN($AA$1),
  IF(ISTEXT(Sheet1!AD1),Sheet1!AD1,""),
  IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$Z1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$A1:$Z1),0),0)+COLUMN()-COLUMN($AA$1))="","",
  INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:$Z1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(Sheet1!$A1:$Z1),0),0)+COLUMN()-COLUMN($AA$1)))
  )
```